# How do I configure a different shell for a VS Code SSH Remote?

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

How do the change the shell used for VS Code's integrated terminal when I connect to an [remote ssh workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use remote setting to change the shell for each host. To do this, open the remote workspace in VS Code and run the `Open Remote settings` command:

[image: The Open Remote Settings commands]

Set `terminal.integrated.shell.linux` to point to your shell and save the file:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/usr/bin/fish"
```

[image]

The remote settings apply to all workspaces you open on a given host, but must be configured for each host you connect to.

Comment: this is deprecated now. The new feature settings are using `terminal.integrated.profiles.linux`

Answer (score 19):

Adding to @Matt Bierner's answer.

The newer versions of `vscode` now lets you set up profiles for your terminal and give them your custom name and that name is supposed to be referenced in your *remote settings*.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> -> `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`

**user configs**

```json
...
"terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
    "s-mann-term": {
        "path": "/usr/bin/zsh"
    },
    "bash": {
        "path": "bash"
    },
    "zsh": {
        "path": "zsh"
    },
    "my-fav-term": {
        "path": "fish"
    }
},
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "s-mann-term"
...
```

This will make all hosts to default to `/usr/bin/zsh` (I just used `path` key in my profile but there are bunch of [other options](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_configuring-profiles) that you can modify)

> NOTE: You can add multiple profiles for the same shell as well. For example, 5 differently configured `zsh` profiles.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> -> `Preferences: Open Remote Settings (SSH: az-box1)`

**az-box1 configs**

```json
...
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "my-fav-term"
...
```

But *az-box1* will default to `fish`

Comment: For the newer versions of vscode, this answer is the right answer!. Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify why you have `/usr/bin/zsh` for s-mann-term and just `zsh` for zsh profiles?

Comment: I am asking because if I use `terminal.integrated.shell.linux` in my remote settings.json it works, but this solution (above) does not.

Comment: I'm running code 1.86 and this doesn't work for me.  I think maybe you can only open the remote settings for a host once you have successfully connected to that host; unfortunately, I can't connect to the host because it doesn't have `bash` installed, leaving me with something of a chicken and an egg.

Answer (score 2):

None of the above answers worked for me and I've been trying to get the default shell to be zsh for many months. What finally worked was adding the following to the top of my `.bashrc`:

```
if [[ "$TERM_PROGRAM" == "vscode" ]]; then
  # ~/.profile is run by the login shell (this is what ssh uses)
  # ~/.bashrc is run by the interactive shell (this is what vscode uses)
  # Therefore, we only need to change the shell to zsh here since
  # vscode will run ~/.bashrc for us.
  exec zsh -l
fi
```

Comment: Where does TERM_PROGRAM come from? I'm not seeing it set when connecting to a windows machine with the OpenSSH service running and its shell set to `C:/program files/git/bin/bash.exe`