# Setting the terminal shell (and default) on an SSH remote in VS Code

Tags: shell, visual-studio-code, ssh, terminal

When connecting in Visual Studio Code (1.85.1) to remote linux machines (ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS) from my mac (13.6.2 M2), VSCode seems to ignore my remote settings file (me@remote:~/.vscode-server/data/Machine/settings.json) that should dictate the preferred shells and default shell for the terminal and always falls back on /bin/bash, which happens to be particularly useless in VSCode for some reason:

```
me@remote:/usr/bin$ ls
bash: ls: command not found
```

/bin/bash works normally in a regular SSH terminal:

```
me@remote:~$ ls .vscode
argv.json  extensions  launch.json
```

I have tried to configure the remote settings based on this article: [How do I configure a different shell for a VS Code SSH Remote?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55978281/how-do-i-configure-a-different-shell-for-a-vs-code-ssh-remote)

In the command palette: Open Remote Settings (JSON) (SSH:remote). This opens the settings.json file which looks like this:

```
{
"terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
  "s-mann-term": {
    "path": "/usr/bin/bash"
  },
  "bash": {
    "path": "/usr/bin/bash"
  }
},
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "s-mann-term"}
```

However, when I launch a new terminal in VSCode and echo $SHELL, I always get /bin/bash, regardless of whether it selects default, or I select s-mann-term or bash from the pull-down menu:
[image]

And yet, I have no problem using /usr/bin/bash in SSH remote shells outside of VS Code:

```
me@remote:~$ ll /usr/bin/bash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1.2M Apr 18  2022 /usr/bin/bash*
```

Other responses to this question mostly predate the shift in VSCode from terminal.integration.shell to terminal.integrated.shell, which is apparently deprecated.

Comment: `$SHELL` normally contains the login shell for the user, not whatever shell you happen to be running at the moment. It's not proof of what shell vscode started for you. And besides, `/bin/bash` and `/usr/bin/bash` are likely to be the same program.

Comment: The variable `SHELL` is, AFIK, automatically set by bash, unless it has been set to a different value in the parent process; for instance `SHELL=foo bash -c 'printenv SHELL'` prints _foo_. I don't see how this is related to your problem of doing a ssh. However, I don't see any `ssh` actual command in your question, and this **would** be relevant for your problem.

Comment: I see. Indeed `echo $0` shows that the settings.json file is working to switch between the shells as intended, given the path. Oddly, despite trying /bin/bash, /usr/bin/bash, and /usr/bin/zsh, I still lack basic functionality like `ls` and `grep`, while `pwd` and `echo` work fine, but there might be some reason the sys admin for the server set it up like that.
This is entirely through an SSH connection over a jump server in VSCode, i.e., VSCode is running a local window in which remote files and settings are being used.

Comment: All of the "command not found" errors are probably because your command PATH is set incorrectly, so your shell isn't searching the correct directories for commands. It's presumably due to some interaction between the contents of your bash startup files on the remote system and the exact commands being invoked by vscode.

Comment: It might be useful to use `ps` to get a complete list of the processes invoked by vscode for the remote session, including their command line arguments. You'll probably find an sshd instance, then a /bin/bash instance, then an instance of whatever shell you asked vscode to start.

Answer (score 0):

The settings.json file on the remote server is working properly to set the integrated terminal shell in VSCode. The problem lies elsewhere in VSCode, because a normal terminal connection via SSH pulls up the /bin/bash shell by default and it works as expected, while the /bin/bash (or any other) shell used by the VSCode terminal does not (i.e., no access to basic commands like `ls` or `grep`).